# How to modify c# .NET dictionary from matlab

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, dictionary

Let's say that I have the following C# class

```
namespace MySpecialNamespace
{
    public class DeleteMe
    {
        public Dictionary<String, String> D;
        public DeleteMe()
        {
            D = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"A", "myA"},
                { "B", "myB"}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I can create an instance of this class from Matlab using the following

```
LoadDotNETAssembly('pathToCSharpBuildFolder','DeleteMe.dll');
q = MySpecialNamespace.DeleteMe()
```

where LoadDotNetAssembly is a convenience wrapper around Matlab's NET.addAssembly() function. I can read a value from this instance of a dictionary using

```
q.D.Item('A')
```

However, I cannot set the value of a particular dictionary item with

```
q.D.Item('A') = 'foo'
Array formation and indexing are not allowed on .NET objects.
```

What is the proper syntax for modifying c# .NET dictionary items?

Comment: yes, q.D.Item('A') compiles and give the value of the "A" key within the dictionary, which is "myA"

Comment: You have to remember that q.D.Item('A') is being called from Matlab, where 'A' is a string

Comment: Does `q.D['A'] = 'foo'` work? Or `q.D('A') = 'foo'`? Can you use `Remove` then `Add`?

Comment: neither of those work, giving various errors. Removing then adding is a possibility, but seems like using a hammer when all that's needed is a paperclip

Comment: >> q.D['A'] = 'foo'
 q.D['A'] = 'foo'
    ↑
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
 
>> q.D('A') = 'foo'
Array formation and indexing are not allowed on .NET objects.

Comment: Like I said, Remove/Add works, but it's rather painful when modifying a more complicated dictionary than <string,string>. It's like using a sledge hammer to accomplish a fine tweak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official method for setting values in a `List<T>` by index [is to use `Item(index, newValue)`](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/accessing-items-in-net-collections.html)

I don't currently have Matlab handy, but it's *possible* that this directly translate to `Dictionary<T>`

```
D.Item('A', 'foo')
```